# Enable static data reload in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following issue in IntelliJ IDEA: after I start up Tomcat in debug mode, I am trying to modify static data (JavaScript, CSS, HTML, etc), but these changes aren't updated automatically in web application. The changes are applied only after rebuilding the WAR. How would I switch on automatic static data reload in IDEA or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Hot reload is not possible when using **war** artifact, switch to the **exploded** artifact and refer to the the help section for the [Update](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html) feature.

Comment: Thanks you. Turning the update on frame deactivation option on in the run or debug tool window helps me